# Matlab figure saved as .eps appears in 'horizontal sections' when opened in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: matlab, figure, adobe-illustrator, eps

I normally save my matlab figures as .eps and then make them better looking using Adobe Illustrator. This works for most figures but not all.

For example I plotted my data using the [violin.m](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/45134-violin-plot) function from file exchange. When I save it as .eps and open it in Illustrator, I don't get an editable figure as I usually do. Instead, My figure appears chopped in horizontal sections, and all I can do is delete them (like in the figure below).[image: my .eps as seen in Illustrator]

Is there anything I can do in either matlab or Illustrator to be able to edit the figure? 
I don't need an .eps file, I just need to be able to edit it.

---

EDITS:

1. I tried @MattSchmatt's suggestion of using the print2eps function but I had the same problem.
2. Saving as .pdf doesn't solve the problem, because the image I get is not editable in Illustrator (plus, I also get the horizontal 'chunks').
3. A minimal, complete and verifiable example requires matlab, the violin function linked above and illustrator. But if it helps, here's the matlab code to produce a similar figure. I save by clicking on Figure -> save as. (But as I said above I tried the print2eps function and that was the same).

   `X = rand(100,6);
   figure; violin(X)`
4. I tried the following, didn't work either. 
   `set(gcf, 'Renderer', 'painters')`

Comment: I'm exporting all my plots with export_fig [(link)](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig) and find it quite good. It can export to .eps too. Does this help?

Comment: @MattSchmatt Thanks for the suggestion but no :( I tried print2eps and I have the same issue.

Comment: I see, then i can't help. But you could add that info to your question.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Two things to try. Change the [`'Renderer'`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure-properties.html#zmw57dd0e228962) to `'painters'`. Or export as a PDF instead of EPS.

Comment: @horchler Thanks for the suggestions, both promising but neither worked. Updated my question accordingly.

Comment: I can't replicate with R2015b on OS X. Both EPS and PDF files open in Illustrator (CS6) with their vector content intact. How are you exporting? I just use File > Save As... from the figure's menu. What `version` of Matlab are you using?

Comment: @Horchler, thanks! I'm using R2012a (and CS6 on OS X). It worked now with a R2014. If you add an answer i'll accept it, thanks again.

Comment: I also had no problem with R2015b on OS X with Illustrator CC 2015.

Answer (score 0):

As the author of the question suggests, I also wasn't able to export an editable (vectorized) .eps file into Illustrator. However, exporting it as .pdf does the trick. The 'fill' for the violin plots is weird, though, and has horizontal sections (perhaps something to do with the way the density estimate is being plotted?) all over. I was able to fix this and make the plots normal (with solid filled shades): select all the horizontal sections/chunks using the magic wand tool, and then increase opacity to 100% (it is set to 50 based on the exported file). Once all the required edits are made, export the file as .tiff and it seems to look fine. Hope this replicates, and thus helps! (my MATLAB version is 2016, and Illustrator version is the CS5)